# java left pad zeros in a string with spaces in the middle

Tags: java, spaces, pad

I'm looking for a performance solution in multi threading processes in JSE 1.7.0.52 for this problem:

I have a String for example: "   12697 26    "

I need to have a string as "00012697 26    "

This means that I can't use String.formatter method as:

```
String c = "   12697 26    ";<br />
String.format( "%1$15s", c);<br /><br />
```

Because the result will be the same of the input. The 15s fill the string on left with spaces but I need to fill by zeros....

Some performace solution exists in new version of Java ?
Kind regards

Comment: Why do you need this?

Comment: @EJP Because I generate by listagg in oracle 11g a lot of string as a "vector in other system" concatenation for an integration partitioned by an attribute and now I have this problem.

Comment: @Karna It isn't a duplicate please read carefully the question...

Comment: I don't like to use RPAD in oracle because the sql is very heavy as costs ...

Comment: Why are there exactly 3 zeros?

Comment: @Henry because I need to send this data to a file for host system and the track defined for this file have this field defined for 15 characters...

Comment: But your example has only 12 characters ...

Comment: *Why* does the 'track defined for this file have this field defined for 15 characters' with a space in the middle but leading zeros to the left? The impression here is that you don't understand the requirement yourself. NB the cost of an `RPAD` is trivial compared to the cost of the query and retrievals.

Comment: @Henry In editing the string is write as 15 character but when I publish the question the front end of stackoverflow site is show as a cut string ...

Comment: People the problem is described.... I have a string with spaces in the middle and in front of first character different of space... I need to right pad respect the first not white space.....

Comment: Merely repeating yourself doesn't answer the question.

Answer (score 1):

```
String input = "   12697 26    ";
StringBuilder s = new StringBuilder(input);
for (int i = 0  ; i<s.length() && s.charAt(i) == ' ' ; i++) {
    s.setCharAt(i, '0');
}

System.out.printf("'%s'", s.toString());
```

'00012697 26    '

Comment: Wrong solution on tail string I don't need zeros on tail...

Comment: updated to reflect your requirements now

Comment: Thanks @MrWiggles this is the same solution that I'm using. The problem is that I managing  1.2gb of file in output with 6.000.000 of records in concatenation.... and this solution is heavy ...

Comment: What do you mean by "heavy".  This is only a memory copy into the StringBuilder and will iterate *only* for the leading spaces.  Have you done any profiling to see if this won't work for you?

Comment: I'm searching now to use awk I suppose that it's more performance before to send the result file... People, thanks a lot for your help ...

Comment: If you're doing work with the file in Java and then passing the output to awk to add the zeroes it most certainly will _not_ be more performant

Answer (score 0):

Code is..

```
String func(String s)
{
    int flag=0;
    String temp="":
    for(int i=0;i<s.length();i++)
    {
        if(flag==0&&s.charAt(i)==' ')
        temp+="0";
        else
        {
            flag=1;
            temp+=s.charAt(i);
         }
    }
    return temp;
  }
```

Comment: Ok boys thank you the code I can write alone.... exists a performance solution ?

Comment: What do you mean by "performance solution"?

Comment: performance solution is a solution that have low resources used in java 1.7.0.51

Comment: It is of O(n) where n is length of string and I think it is one of the best time complexity...

Comment: Actually, your solution is O(n^2) because of the string concatenations. The first part of the string is copied to a new memory area whenever you add a character. Using a `StringBuilder` would make it O(n).